# Eloquent Relationship. Has Many relation with different keys

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

## Background

I have a model, Contract that belongs to the User model through two keys, `user_id` and `recipient_id`. How would I be able to query all the contracts for a user using `$user->contracts` keeping the two key into consideration.

\App\Contract model has this

```
$protected $fillable = [
   ...
   'user_id',
   'recipient_id',
   ...
];

public function user ()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function recipient()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'recipient_id', 'id');
}
```

\App\User model has this

```
public function contracts ()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Contract::class);
}
```

To get the user contracts, I have to do this

```
$contracts = Contract::where('user_id', $user->id)
   ->orWhere('recipient_id', $user->id)
   ->get();
```

What I would like is something like this. `\App\Contract`

```
public function user () {
  return $this->belongsTo([User::class, User::class], ['user_id', 'recipient_id']);
}
```

I am aware of https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep and it doesn't solve my problems.

How do I go about it?

Comment: Laravel does not support relationship with two different foreign key.

Comment: You could create a scope for the contract model to do Contact::forUser($user->id). If you really want to do $user->contracts, I would create both separate relationships and then an eloquent accessor to concatenate them. Both approaches dont seem elegant enough though, so i'd review the database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way, so, I ended doing this in *ContractController.php*

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($user->isAdmin()) {
            return Contract::latest()->get();
        }

        $contracts = Contract::where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->orWhere('recipient_id', $user->id)
            ->get();

        return $contracts;
    }
```